# Excel unable to get css styles from xlsxwriter python

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am creating a report in xlsxwriter with some styles like merged cells, font styles, colors, etc...

All code seems right, I'm following the docs and tips and the file is being saved correctly but when I try to open the file on Microsoft Excel it says that the file has some corrupted styles.

When I open the file on Libre Office, Numbers and Wps, everything works well..

Comment: You will need to create a small working example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @jmcnamara I'm sorry to not put an example of my code, that's because I have a big one but I have good news, I've just found the problem few minutes ago and it was my mistake. I was setting a font_size style with px as string like this '18px'. My apologize and thanks.