# Format Multiple Excel Files before exporting them with Python

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have a dataframe that has one column which contains 4 different countries. **For each country** I want to export a **different** excel file in my desktop but I want to apply the format once to all of them. Write now I have managed to separate the files (couldn't make it with a for loop though), but I can not pull through the formatting :(

So far I have done this:

```
df_Spain = df.loc[(df.country == 'SPAIN')]
df_Italy = df.loc[(df.country == 'ITALY')]
df_France= df.loc[(df.country == 'FRANCE')]
df_Germany= df.loc[(df.country == 'GERMANY')]


df_Spain .to_excel (r'C:\Users\Desktop\Spain_Analysis_.xlsx', sheet_name='Spain', index = False, header=True)
df_Italy.to_excel (r'C:\Users\Desktop\Italy_Analysis_.xlsx', sheet_name='Italy', index = False, header=True)
```

.... and so on for the other 2 countries

I want each excel file to have:

1. headers with auto-width
2. headers with colored background
3. Freeze first row and first column

Extra question: Is there a way to have a css file that I can always use instead of writing python code over and over again to every script?

Comment: 1,2,3 are possible using XlsxWriter. Extra one might not. [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54449209/excel-unable-to-get-css-styles-from-xlsxwriter-python)

Comment: hi, the link your "similar question" redirects is not a similar issue. I don't know hot to format all those three ".to_excel" reports at once. Thank you,